# How to avoid dhall-format convert natural language Text to code point?

Tags: dhall

I want to write Japanese sentence as Text in dhall file.
But the format subcommand convert them to code points.

```
> dhall version
1.18.0
> echo  '"Haskellは純粋関数型言語のひとつです"' | dhall format
"Haskell\u306F\u7D14\u7C8B\u95A2\u6570\u578B\u8A00\u8A9E\u306E\u3072\u3068\u3064\u3067\u3059"
```

Formatted sentence doesn't make sense.
How can I keep Japanese Text as is?
Or, should I always use the [raw text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dhall-1.18.0/docs/Dhall-Tutorial.html#g:17) feature for Japanese sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by [dhall-1.19.0](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/releases/tag/1.19.0).

Now `dhall format` preserves unicode.

Thank you dhall team!